# Lightroom Tethered shooting not working

Tags: lightroom, nikon-d5100, tethering, windows-10

I'm using a Nikon D5100 and a Surface Pro 3 on windows 10.

I'm having issues with the tethered shooting in that 9 times out of 10 it doesn't detect a camera.

I can't for the life of me figure out why it works sometimes and not others.

Anyone got any ideas of how I can make the connection more reliable and stable?

Comment: What exact version of Lightoom?

Comment: Are you sure the USB cable's good?

Comment: Lightroom version: CC 2015.2 [ 1044713 ]

D5100 has latest firmware update.

USB cables is the official cable and is definitely good.

Contacted Nikon and they have suggested it is a known issue and told me to contact Adobe. Adobe support was beyond useless, took their agent over an hour to simply say Adobe haven't tested the D5100 for windows 10 support and can't offer any assistance.

Comment: Strangely, I can get it to work sometimes. But after shooting aprox 10+ photos, the transfer gets slower and slower until it no longer transfers any photos. At this stage if I try to disconnect and reconnect the camera it no longer detects it.

Comment: I don't have an exact solution, but I would dig a little into my "event viewer" and see if any application, or system errors show up. I'd also run an event log every time I tethered the camera. You may have a conflicting service with the tethering part of the application. Services are easy to find and modify.

Answer (score 1):

I use this infrequently with digitizing negatives, and there are a bunch of issues that can come up, and often this is a bit of "close your eyes, change a few things, cross your fingers and hope".  Some specifics I've found:  (1) format the card in the camera before you start (I realize the card is not to be used, but when you plug in a camera to the computer, the first thing the (some? all?) driver does is try to itemize all the photos, and it can appear to hang for minutes if there are a lot of photos), (2) reboot before testing (sadly even in 2016), start with camera off, plug in, turn on, (3) check and remove any competing drivers or other software that might have had drivers for it, (4) check in Device Manager and look for the warning symbol on any device on the USB bus, and try to resolve it as needed.  The issue you have with progressively slower transfer though, does not sound familiar.  In most cases for me it either works, or fails, not something in the middle.  If practical try on a different PC as well, and if you know someone try a different camera on the SP3.  Finally and not pretty, you might clear out your lightroom preferences and reset to basically a fresh install (be sure you know how to put them back); Adobe recommends that, though I have yet to see it truly solve a problem, it will be high on their list if you ask them.

Answer (score 0):

Lr is up to 2015.5.1. http://blogs.adobe.com/lightroomjournal/2016/04/lightroom-cc-2015-5-1-now-available.html. Not sure if that matters, but I seem to recall one update had something about tethering.